# How does Jupyter notebook tell is a command you typed is a terminal command or python command?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I just found that without typing "!" you can still run some terminal commands in the Jupyter notebook. Such as, "ls", "pwd", "cd", etc.
But when I try to run some other terminal command, for example, "tree", it tells me "NameError: name 'tree' is not defined". It means that Jupyter notebook is interpreting that command as a Python command.

Question: how does Jupyter tell if a command is a terminal command or Python command when you don't type "!" before the terminal command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jupyter has a set of shell-like commands that it recognizes regardless of whether you add a `!` in front of them or not (given that your `automagic` is set to on, otherwise you have to prefix them with `!`). Some of the most common include `cd`, `cat`, `cp`, `man`, `rm` or `pwd`. The full list is [available here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html).

Unfortunately `tree` is not one of these commands, so you'd be better off executing that in a dedicated shell.

Comment: It's not Jupyter but IPython to be precise.